# Cookies not being set when login using Google Login and passport

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am using nodejs and react on heroku and passport js. I have code that logs a user in using google; however, a cookie is not being set for that user. The first time the user tries to log in using google, he is redirected back to the server endpoint and he get's an error "Unable to verify authorization request state".

Here's my code

```
  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
            clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID_LOGIN,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET_LOGIN,
            callbackURL: process.env.DOMAIN_NAME + "/user/google/callback"
        },
        function(issuer, profile, cb) {
            User.findOrCreateGoogleUser(profile.id, profile.emails[0].value).then(result => {
                return cb(null, result[0]);
            }).catch (err => {
                console.dir(err);
                return cb(err, null, {
                    message: err
                })
            });
        }
    ));

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
    User.fetchById(id).then(result => {
        cb(null, result[0]);
    }).catch(err => {
        cb(err, null);
    });
});

router.get("/google/callback", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("google", {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
        if (err || !user) {
            console.dir(err);
            var message =
                info && info.message
                    ? encodeURIComponent(info.message + " Please try again or try another login method.")
                    : encodeURIComponent(
                    "There was an error logging you in. Please try another login method."
                    );
            return res.redirect(
                process.env.BASE_CLIENT_URL + "/login?error=" + message
            );
        }
        req.login(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.dir(err);
                return res.redirect(
                    process.env.BASE_CLIENT_URL +
                    "/login?error=" +
                    encodeURIComponent(
                        "Invalid User. Please try another account or register a new account."
                    )
                );
            }
            const payload = {
                sub: user.id,
            };
            const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRESIN,
            });
            res.clearCookie("auth");
            res.cookie("auth", token);
            res.redirect(process.env.BASE_CLIENT_URL + "/loginsuccess");
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

router.get(
    "/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        scope: ["email"],
    })
);


const session = require("express-session");
app.use (
    session ({
        secret: "FMfcgzGllVtHlrXDrwtpNdhLRXlNtVzl18088dda1",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        proxy: true,
        rolling: true,
        cookie: {
            expires: 60 * 60 * 24,
            secure: (app.get('env') === 'production'),
            sameSite: 'lax'
        }
    })
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. did you get any answer? I am facing the same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75382638/passport-js-is-not-saving-cookies-in-the-browser-i-upload-frontend-to-netlify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Was running into the same issue. Pretty much, the reason setting cookies via the auth callback URL is because cookies only get set when the request is coming from the same domain as your API. And when that `/google/callback` URL is hit, the request is coming from `accounts.google.com` instead of your app. So your server is responding with a cookie, but its responding to Google's request, not yours. The cookie is not automatically passed.

To fix it, you can specify the `domain` of your cookie to match your URLs. In my situation, my API lives at `api.example.com` and my app lives at `app.example.com`. In this example I'm using the [cookie package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) to set the headers.

So instead of `res.cookie`, do:

```js
res.setHeader(
 'Set-Cookie',
  cookie.serialize('XSRF-TOKEN', YOUR_OBJECT, { // XSRF-TOKEN is the name of your cookie
    sameSite: 'lax', // lax is important, don't use 'strict' or 'none'
    httpOnly: process.env.ENVIRONMENT !== 'development', // must be true in production
    path: '/',
    secure: process.env.ENVIRONMENT !== 'development', // must be true in production
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 52, // 1 year
    domain: process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'development' ? '' : `.example.com`, // the period before is important and intentional
  })
)
```

In this example, the cookie is named `XSRF-TOKEN` with a value of whatever `YOUR_OBJECT` is. The Path attribute sets the path for which the cookie should be sent, and the Domain attribute specifies that the cookie should be sent to all subdomains of example.com. The Secure attribute ensures that the cookie is only sent over HTTPS, and the HttpOnly attribute ensures that the cookie is only accessible via HTTP(S) requests, not via client-side JavaScript.

Once the cookie is set, the browser will send it back to `app.example.com` with any subsequent requests from `accounts.google.com`, allowing the server to identify the user and maintain their session.

Note that setting a cookie with a domain attribute of `.example.com` will make the cookie accessible to all subdomains of example.com, including `app.example.com`. If you *only* want the cookie to be accessible to `app.example.com`, you can set the Domain attribute to `app.example.com` instead.