# passport js is not saving cookies in the browser I upload frontend to Netlify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, google-oauth, passport.js

I am creating a mern stack chat application. I used google authentication using passport js. everything is working fine in the localhost. I can log in and the user get saved in the database but when I upload the frontend to Netlify it does not work. I can login and the user get saved in the Mongodb database but cookies doesn't get saved.

// passport.js middle ware

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from "passport-google-oauth20";
import User from "./models/user.js";
dotenv.config();
passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
  cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, cb) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
    cb(null, user);
  });
});
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL,
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      console.log(" google strategy called");
      User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id }).then((currentUser) => {
        if (currentUser) {
          // already have user
          console.log("user find one called");
          cb(null, currentUser);
        } else {
          // if not, create user in our db
          new User({
            name: profile.displayName,
            googleId: profile.id,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            picture: profile.photos[0].value,
            membership: "free",
          })
            .save()
            .then((newUser) => {
              cb(null, newUser);
            });
        }
      });
    }
  )
);
```

// index.js

```
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://taupe-starburst-7fab32.netlify.app",
    methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
Connection();
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    keys: [process.env.SESSION_SECRET],

    // Cookie Options
    domain: "https://taupe-starburst-7fab32.netlify.app",
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hour
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
  })
);
// to solve session.regenarate issue
app.use(function (request, response, next) {
  if (request.session && !request.session.regenerate) {
    request.session.regenerate = (cb) => {
      cb();
    };
  }
  if (request.session && !request.session.save) {
    request.session.save = (cb) => {
      cb();
    };
  }
  next();
});
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/auth", router);

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () =>
  console.log("server running")
);
```

// auth.js

```
import express from "express";
import passport from "passport";

const router = express.Router();

//sunccess redirect
router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: "successfull",
      user: req.user,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Unauthorized: User is not logged in",
    });
  }
});

//failure redirect
router.get("/login/failed", (req, res) => {
  res.status(401).json({
    success: false,
    message: "failure",
  });
});

// authenticate
router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["email", "profile"] })
);

// callback

router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    failureRedirect: "/login/failed",
  })
);

//logout
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.redirect(`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/login`);
  });
});

export default router;
```

// React Frontend

```
function Login() {
  const google = () => {
    window.open(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}auth/google`, '_self');
  };
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={google}>
      Login with Google
    </button>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: do I need to store frontend and backend in the same folder and try with heroku?

Comment: I think it is happening because the frontend and backend are in different domains. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the exact same issue. My Next.js app is on netlify and my node app is on render.

Comment: hi bsmith. I ended up hosting my frontend and backend in the same URL and it was working.